# Getting .value observers on specific children from a firebase database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've got a list of topics that users can subscribe to or not. On the home page, I'm displaying, in a tableview, the list of rooms a user has subscribed to. I don't know if I'm overcomplicating this, but I'm having a hard time understanding how to get live observers on all of those individual topics.

My database looks like :

```
 topics:
      stackoverflow:
         users: 50
         lastPost : 2384938943
      twitch: 
         users : 50
         lastPost : 209340932843
   users: 
       user1:
         favoritedRooms:
           twitch : true
           stackoverflow : true
```

So I'm able to get the list of favorited rooms from the current user and store that into an array. From there though, I"m not sure how to update my tableview if one of these rooms has a value update. If I do something like store the favorited topics in an array when I fetch them and then do something like

```
 for topic in favoritedTopicNames {
   somereference.observe(.value) {
       //make a Topic object
      // append it to an array I'm basing my table off of and reloadData
     }   
}
```

then I'm setting up individual .value observers for each topic. I can't do this because this means each time a topic's observer is called I'm only getting that ONE topic back, so I can't clear out my array, append and reload because I'll end up with only 1 topic.

So basically my question is, if I need to first query a specific list of topics to observe that are a subset of my topics node, how do I keep a live feed going on those specific topics so that if the user count or lastPost numbers are changed, I can update my labels and keep the information live?

Comment: try getting all data at once I used this concept in my chat app . do one thing get all the topics in a array from there call a function getUserTopoicsArray in this just compare a total topics array with userTopic Array and get a new array with required value and then reload tableView this will solve your one problem of not getting al data at once and will save your memory and network issue too. secondly to get live updates you can call the function in which you are getting total Topics list in Willappear it will check your database continuously

Comment: though your method to get data is okay but I do not prefer it due to low internet connectivity sometimes for live updates call your function in willAppear